# Executing cmd commands with NodeJs

Tags: node.js, exec

I am executing some commands (`npm install, git clone etc`) in `nodejs` with `exec` function of `nodejs child_process's module` which is working really cool. I am able to get the expected results. What I am still not able to achieve is, to show the `output/stdout` on command window. I've tried piping the output to `main process` like

```
`exec('npm install xyz').stdout.pipe(process.stdout);`
```

but I still don't see the progress bar kind of thing with I see in case of running `npm install xyz` directly in cmd.

I've also tried to listen on the event `exec('npm install xyz').stdout.on('data', callbackfunction)`, but no luck.

I am probably missing something. Is there any other event that I need to listen on for these kind of commands (`npm install, git clone etc`)?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it's STDOUT and not STDERR?

Comment: @Brad , No. I am not sure if it is `stdout`. But It's definitely not  `stderr`.

Comment: Well, you have to pick one as there are no other standard streams.  :-)

Comment: If I listen on `stderr` it does show the error on command window like `npm war or dedicated ` kind of warnings. But nothing else

Comment: Yes, I know that. That's why I am stuck.

Comment: So much for "definitely not stderr" then, 'eh?

Comment: coz, If I pipe the `stderr` stream on the main process I don't see the success events like progress bar etc. I only see if there is any error while resolving dependencies in case of `npm install` or cloning repositories in case of  `git clone `

Comment: NPM probably knows it's not running in the context of a TTY, and that its output has been redirected.  Therefore, it isn't going to output the TTY control characters needed to display progress bars and what not.

Comment: yeah, may be. Is there any workaround ? :p